# Did Kiranjit Kaur set herself ablaze?

Tags: india, school

[This report](http://www.ndtv.com/cities/punjab-teacher-dies-after-setting-herself-ablaze-410587) claims she did but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IT5CCUU620) of the same incident indicates it was an accident.

[Another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhUT5hQFrVY) reporting the same incident.

So, did she intentionally do that or was it an accident?

Comment: Please give your question some context. Who is KK? Where? When? This is a worldwide forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [The jobless of Punjab find a new way to government jobs — threaten suicide from atop high water tanks](http://archive.tehelka.com/story_main46.asp?filename=Ne240710UNEMPLOYMENT.asp)

> The teachers doused themselves with petrol. They tried to light a match, but the wind blew it out. So they lit a shawl they would set themselves afire with. As the shawl burst into flames, the teachers jumped back in horror. But Kiranjit was already ablaze. She was holding the bottle of petrol in her hands, and the flames engulfed her.
>
> The next day, Kiranjit died.

The link also includes a photograph with the caption:

> Kiranjit Kaur Attwal in flames on February 7 [2010], at Kapurthala